# Sequence of Sysout result

Tags: java

While practising Java arrays in Eclipse, I have encountered this weird behaviour of arrays.

```
public class base3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]= new int[25];
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        //System.out.println(arr[25]);
        System.out.println(arr[-10]);
    }
}
```

Output of this is:

```
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -10
at base3.main(base3.java:6)
```

But as soon as I change the index of third sysout from -10 to -11, the sequence of output changes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -11
at base3.main(base3.java:6)
0
```

So why does the output sequence changes along with array index.

Comment: I dint get this type of behaviour [see](http://ideone.com/K9CkvJ)

Comment: @Swanand Pangam it shoud consistent in both cases, execute using commend prompt

Comment: What you see in the console (`0` before of after the exception) is probably just a multi-thread interleaving. I highly suspect you can obtain both output, with any out of range index (eg. -10, -11 or else). Did you try to repeat your experiment several times ?

Comment: I again tried it on my Eclipse IDE but same results.

Comment: @johand. yes the results are like: up to -10 its normal. From -11 to -24 its reverse and after -25 its again normal.

Comment: @SwanandPangam it doesn't make sense, the sequence should be the same.

Comment: If @johand. is right, the results over repeated sets of inputs should not give deterministic results. So it might go one way in one run and the other way in another for a given input.

Comment: Nothing changes!!! just run it from command line. You are observing some odd behavior with Eclipse and shouldn't be thought of like "Sequence of Sys-out results change in java"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening due to the the output is written to different file. The output 0 is printed to standard output(fd 1) and the exception to standard error(fd 2). You could see this when you redirect standard error to `/dev/null`

```
❯ java base3 2>/dev/null
0
```

See how you don't get exception here. So the order here will not be predictable due to output written to different files.

Comment: Then can you elaborate why this happens in a particular fashion only like I have explained in my last comment below question. Anyways thnx.

Comment: @SwanandPangam I tried from -11 and -25 and all the output were in order.

Answer (score 1):

The [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) says `Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.`.

I think you are looking at a race condition between standard error and standard out to print things to the console. When the exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` gets thrown, it is not handled by printing to `System.out` but to `System.err`. Since both streams have to share the console resource the order in which they get access determines the order of the print statements.

The change of -10 to -11 should not influence the result. It is the time between the call to `System.out.println(arr[0]);` and `System.out.println(arr[-10]);` that influences the order of the output.